# opencsv not recognizing all columns in line

Tags: java, opencsv

I'm using opencsv 2.3 for Java.  I set up my CSVReader object like this to handle

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath()));
```

In my file, I have the following lines:

```
"001-07110-004","BLOWER KEY","York"
"032MF","Liquid Line Filter Drier, 1/4" FEMALE X MALE, 3CU","Parker Hannifin"
```

The data was exported from a SQL Server table to a CSV file.

OpenCSV correctly recognizes three columns for the first line, but only two for the second line.

How would I configure OpenCSV to recognize three columns of data for the second line?

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate post! I resolved the issue by recreating the CSV file. Instead of using the SQL Server Export wizard, I copied the contents of the view to an Excel spreadsheet, then saved as CSV. Excel added the necessary double quotes necessary for opencsv to recognize the data correctly. I'm surprised the SQL Server Export wizard doesn't have a proper CSV option, but then again this is Microsoft I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that in the middle of your field you have an unescaped double quote in the middle of the field which is throwing everything off.

Try toggling the value of `strictQuotes` you are passing into the `CSVReader` but if that does not work you will have to escape the quote in the file either with the escape character (`\` by default) or another double quote.

Comment: "Almost definitely a duplicate" - then please flag it as such and/or leave a comment, rather than add an answer.